# ${{p^k}\choose{j}}\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ for $0 < j < p^k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

> $${{p^k}\choose{j}}\equiv 0\pmod{p}.\ \ \  \text{for $0 < j < p^k$ and p is prime}$$

I can show this for $k=1$ using the fact that in denominator all numbers are less than $p$. I need hint for proving this for $k>1$.

Comment: Of course, note that, for $ k = 1 $, it is just [Lucas' Theorem](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Lucas'_Theorem).

Comment: $\binom{n}{j}$ is divisible by a prime $p$ if and only if the addition $j + (n-j)$ has at least one carry when done in base $p$. For $n = p^k$, the base-$p$ representation of $n$ is $10\dotsc0$, so the addition produces a carry unless one summand is $0$.

Comment: @AhaanRungta: I think that Lucas implies this right away for all $k$ (see prof. Lubin's answer).

Comment: Oh wow. Very true. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\binom{p^k}j=p^k\frac{(p^k-1)(p^k-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(p^k-(j-1))}{1\cdot 2\cdot\ldots\cdot j}$$

Now just check that $\;p\mid n\iff p\mid (p^k-n)\;$ so that all possible powers of $\;p\;$ in the fraction's denominator above cancel out with the corresponding powers of $\;p\;$ in the same fraction's numerator...

Comment: I think $j \mid n$ should be considered separately, since $p^k - j$ is not in the numerator, but of course it cant cancel all factors of $p^k$

Answer (score 2):

What you have already shown, in the domain of polynomials in two variables with integer coefficients, and in the language of congruences, is that $(X+Y)^p\equiv X^p+Y^p\pmod p$. Thus, $(X+Y)^{p^2}\equiv(X^p+Y^p)^p\equiv X^{p^2}+Y^{p^2}$, and similarly for higher exponents on the $p$, which proves what you want.