# $(a+b)^p = a^p+b^p$ if $p$ prime and $a,b \in \mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: prime-numbers, field-theory

Can someone please explain why

\begin{align}
(a+b)^p = a^p+b^p
\end{align}

if $p$ is prime number and $a,b \in \mathbb{F}_p$

I tried to proof it that way
\begin{align}
(a+b)^p = \sum_{j=0}^{p}{p \choose j}a^{p-j}b^j = a^p+b^p + \sum_{j=1}^{p-1}{p \choose j}a^{p-j}b^j
\end{align}
but I can't figure out why $\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}{p \choose j}a^{p-j}b^j = 0$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: Each of the terms $\binom{p}{j}$ ($1\leq j\leq p$) is itself divisible by $p$, and therefore, so is their sum. To see that, write the explicit expression for $\binom{p}{j}$ and use the facts that $p$ is prime.

Comment: Check this also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544239/pk-choosej-equiv-0-pmodp-for-0-j-pk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$${p\choose k} = \frac{p(p-1) \ldots (p-k+1)}{k!}$$

If $0<k<p$ all numbers in the denominator are less than $p$, so $p$ cant be reduces. Therefore ${p\choose k}\equiv 0\pmod p$ for $0<k<p$.

So $$(a+b)^p = \sum_{k=0}^{p}a^kb^{p-k}{p\choose k} = a^p + b^p$$

Answer (score 0):

We can write $p!=k!(p-k)!{p\choose k}$. Since $p\mid p!$, it follows $p\mid k!(p-k)!\;\text{ or }\; \displaystyle p\mid  {p\choose k}$  The former cannot happen if $1\leqslant k\leqslant p-1$, so $p\mid  \displaystyle{p\choose k}$.